# vim: remove quickfix highlights

Tags: vim

I just learned about `:grep` in vim which is great for searching in multiple files. 
What troubles me is that when I have found the line I'm after, I'd like to remove all quickfix hightlights. And I cannot find how to do that properly.

The only "solution" I have is to run another :grep for something that does not exist, like `:grep XZYXZ %`. But I have a feeling there must be a real command to remove the quickfix highlights?

edit: see screenshot. I want to remove the red lines (which highlight the :grep matches).

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be "search highlight", not "quickfix highlight".

You can [toggle highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9092033/546861) or simply keep it disabled and use the actual quickfix window to locate and jump to matches (what I do):

```
:vimgrep pattern * | copen
```

Comment: thx for the answer. but that does not work in my vim. I added a screenshot now. the red lines are :grep matches and the underlined _toList_'s are search matches. toggling search highlighting only removes the underlining of toList.

Comment: You are using a special plugin/script/setting that highlights error lines and marks them with a sign. Because `:grep`'s matches are added to the error list they are highlighted like errors and the usual "search highlighting" doesn't apply. Try `:lgrep` which uses the location list instead of the error list.

Comment: It was so much easier to approach your issue with a screenshot.

Comment: you were right about the plugin. found out it was http://github.com/MarcWeber/vim-addon-signs which somehow was drawn into my config. if i remove the plugin, all the red lines dissapear.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
:nohlsearch
```

It will disable the current search highlighting.

Comment: Can write :noh instead for shortness